# Tool for validating SQL Queries against different standards and Databases

Tags: java, database, sql

I am looking for a tool (offline tool, java library, binary or such) (no online tools) which is able to validate SQL Queries against the different SQL Standard Versions or against the features of specific databases.

It would even better match the situation if it was able to enable or disable specific features for validation.